# How to fix blogger template for mobile devices

Tags: blogs, blogger

I have a blog http://bdbloggerhub.com . It's fine in pc but when i visit it with mobile or tab it shows a blank pic above the post pic. How to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding `.img-thumbnail{display:none;}` at the end of your styles.
**or** for particular screen size add the following styles.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px)
.img-thumbnail {
    display none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px)
.img-thumbnail {
    display:none;
}
```

you can also use the `{width:0; height:0}` properties in place of `{display:none}`

Comment: Good to hear that, close this question by marking it answered.